# How to make CSS styles override JavaScript applied styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I create an HTML table dynamically, and apply some styles:**

```
var tbl = document.createElement('table');

tbl.id = "CrewMemberTable";

document.getElementById("CrewMemberPanel").appendChild(tbl);
```

**I then insert rows and cells in the table (just three in this example for brevity):**

```
CrewRow = document.getElementById("CrewMemberTable").insertRow(-1);

CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "this text";
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "some text";
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "more text";
```

**On this last cell, I apply a style, via javascript:**

```
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "more text";
CrewCell.style.backgroundColor = "GREEN";
```

**Finally, I have this style in my .CSS stylesheet:**

```
#CrewMemberTable tr:hover {
    background-color: RED !important;
}
```

When I run it, strictly speaking, I guess nothing is wrong.  It's doing what I asked it to do.

**BUT** - I want the hover to cover the entire row, but instead it only covers the first two cells, and the last cell, where the background color was assigned in javascript, it remains green.  I want the entire row red.

Is this possible?  And how?

Comment: If you have access to both the CSS and the JavaScript why not define a class, in your CSS, for the relevant `<td>` and then add that class, instead of the style, with your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a selector with greater specificity, such as

```
#CrewMemberTable tr:hover, #CrewMemberTable tr:hover td {
    background-color: RED !important;
}
```

You will particularly want to target the cell in addition to the row. (If you wanted you could add a class or id to the cell to facilitate higher-specificity targeting.)

See snippet below for a working example using the code structure you have provided in your question:

```js
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.id = "CrewMemberTable";
document.getElementById("CrewMemberPanel").appendChild(tbl);
CrewRow = document.getElementById("CrewMemberTable").insertRow(-1);
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "this text";
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "some text";
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "more text";
CrewCell = CrewRow.insertCell(-1); CrewCell.innerHTML = "more text";
CrewCell.style.backgroundColor = "GREEN";
```

```css
#CrewMemberTable tr:hover, #CrewMemberTable tr:hover td {
        background-color: RED !important;
    }
```

```html
<div id="CrewMemberPanel"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  There was another answer almost identical, that suggesting letting the background on the hover cells go transparent, thus revealing the hover color.  I think I like yours a bit more, as it doesn't involve a "trick".  It just *sets* the color, instead of doing something to *reveal* a color.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you're only targeting the `<tr>` with CSS but the `GREEN` background is on the `<td>`.

Add this to your CSS

```css
#CrewMemberTable tr:hover td {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

#### Demo

```css
#CrewMemberTable tr:hover {
  background-color: RED !important;
}

#CrewMemberTable tr:hover td {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="CrewMemberPanel">
  <table id="CrewMemberTable">
    <tr>
      <td>this text</td>
      <td>some text</td>
      <td style="background-color: GREEN">more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```