# how to override the style, via css, previously applied with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I' ve already read [this ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976966/how-to-make-css-styles-override-javascript-applied-styles)  without resolve.
I applied the style to "left-conteiner" via javascript, not via the class but via the id! and now I can't overwrite it!

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/andreadc/1jvp0nh3/4/) for reproducible minimal example

```
hideLeftContenier():void{
        console.log('hide')
        let element = document.getElementById('left-conteiner')
        element.style.display = 'none'
}
```

this is the style i want apply, without media query:

```
#left-conteiner{
    display: block;
    position: static;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    flex-basis: 150px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I also tried to override the style via the class selector but with no results.
How to solce? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<button class="icon-button" (click)="showLeftConteiner()">
    <fa-icon class="menu-icon" [icon]="faBars"></fa-icon>
</button>
<div class="conteiner">


    <div class="left-conteiner" id="left-conteiner">
        <div class="filter-box-brand">
            <div class="filterLabel"><b>Brand</b></div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="allBrands" name="allBrands" value="all" 
                [(ngModel)]="checkboxBrandAll" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> all
            </label>
            <div class="checkboxList" *ngFor="let brand of brands ">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{brand.name}}" name="otherBrands" value="{{brand.name}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="brand.checked" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> {{brand.name}}
                </label>
                <label class="labelCount"> ({{brand.count}})</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="filter-box-type">
            <div class="filterLabel"><b>Type</b></div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="allType" name="allTypes" value="all" [(ngModel)]="checkboxTypeAll" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> all</label>
            <div class="checkboxList" *ngFor="let type of types">
                <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="type.checked" id="{{type.name}}" name="otherTypes" value="{{type.name}}" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> {{type.name}}</label><label class="labelCount"> ({{type.count}})</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="hide-button" (click)="hideLeftContenier()">close</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="central-conteiner">
        <div class="gallery" >
            <app-car-card-gallery *ngFor="let car of filteredCars" [car]="car" [parent]="'gallery'" [usersRatings]="usersRatings"></app-car-card-gallery>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you add html code? or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried using => `display: block !important` ? Ideally you should not doing this at all. overriding somethig set by JS via CSS.

Comment: @RayeesAC you are right! done!

Comment: If you have to override an inline style via CSS, you have a fundamental design issue. Apply/Revert the change via JS

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, let's not settle for quick/hacky solutions. :)

Comment: @AdamAzad i doubt if there is a solution to override CSS set by JS via CSS only. Even this sounds odd to me. But `!important` would do the job. - Except for media queries :/

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks for reply! I tried and it don't take the media query style

Comment: @AndreaDiCioccio ideally for better practice you should be using Javascript to set and remove styles as suggested by @ Adam

Comment: @AndreaDiCioccio since you are using Angular, why not just use `*ngIf` to hide and show 'left-conteiner', also to get a html element, `@ViewChild` is preferable in Angular application.

Comment: @QiuZhou 'couse it depends by screen size

Comment: I've added minimal reproducible example

Comment: @AdamAzad I solved with your solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some people have answered yet.
But with your current design, the only solution is to use !important :

```
display: block !important;
```

This is not a good practice because it often leads to "hard-to-maintain" CSS, so I advice you to use Javascript with class toggle like so (example) :

```
    hideLeftContenier():void {
        let element = document.getElementById('left-conteiner')
        element.classList.add('hidden');
    }
```

Then, you need to add a specific CSS rule :

```
#left-conteiner.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```